# Webpack error after upgrading from angular 4 to angular 5

Tags: c#, angular, webpack, asp.net-core-mvc

In an MVC core project, I upgraded a previously working project from Angular 4 to Angular 5 using the command

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.2.0' @angular/common@'^5.2.0' angular/compiler@'^5.2.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.2.0' @angular/core@'^5.2.0' @angular/forms@'^5.2.0' @angular/http@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.2.0' angular/router@'^5.2.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

You can see the version numbers have changed in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "Infobase.Angular",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^4.0.0",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.47",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

I then built and launched the website, getting an error in the Configure method of the Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ConfigureDependencyInjection();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        if (_useIdServer)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
        }


        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

The exception occurs on the line "app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware" and is:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Version of
@angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater.
Current version is "5.2.0".
```

I'm confused as I would expect that 5.2.0 to be higher than 2.3.1. A colleague pointed out that the 5.2.0 was in quotes and that alphabetically "5.2.0" would come before 2.3.1

Any ideas?

Comment: why are all your dependencies devdependencies?

Comment: No idea why - that's how it was presented to me. I have changed it from "devDependencies" to "dependencies", but still get the same error.

Comment: if i were you, look at how dev dependencies are in a new angular project, most things are dependencies but things like `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler-cli` should be in the dev part

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure there were no errors during the `npm intall` ?
Try `npm update`, it might fix it.